# EntityManager persist() method does not insert record to database

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, persist

I have problem with using `EntityManager.persist(Object)` method. Now when i get rid of other problems, by app work without Exception but object is not put in my database.

my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="Chain")
public class Chain implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;
@Column(name = "date")
  private Date date;
@Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
//setters and getters
}
```

my dao class:

```
@Transactional
@Repository("ChainDao")
public class ChainDaoImpl implements ChainDao{


    private EntityManager em;


    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this. em = em;
    }

    public int saveChain(Chain chain) {
        chain.setDate(new Date());
        chain.setId((long)44);
        Boolean a;
        em.persist(chain);

        return 222;
    }
}
```

my xml context:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"></property></bean>


    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory"
            ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
```

and `pereistence.xml`:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="1.0">
       <persistence-unit name="sample">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files -->
        <properties>
           <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
           <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
           <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database"/>
           <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
           <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="pwd"/>
           <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
           <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
        </persistence-unit>

    </persistence>
```

Do anyone have a idea what am i missing?

Comment: Don't assign a ID to your entity, and let hibernate assign it on save (by using one of ID generation mechanisms).

Comment: if i use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` i get `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not get next sequence value`

Comment: Please check your spring-transaction configuration, I had similar problem , and it was due to improper transaction config

Comment: what is wrong with this one?

Comment: i have the same problem with spring and eclipselink... did you get an appropriate solution.. i hav tried everything roryb suggested to no avail...

Comment: OMG, i spent some hours with this problem =P  .. In my case I'm using Camel, Spring and Hibernate + JPA..  I forgot a little detail.  

Was missing the **@Transactional** annotation in  My **@Service** method.

Thanks for **the hint about flush**.  I've just put the flush and the  long awaited exception appears in the log.

nice link about possible causes :
http://www.scarba05.co.uk/blog/2010/02/hibernate-jpa-is-swallowing-my-data-no-save-no-error/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you getting a specific exception? It would be helpful to know what it is if you are.

There are a number of similar problems to this already on Stackoverflow:

[Spring transactional context doesn't persist data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265783/spring-transactional-context-doesnt-persist-data?rq=1)

[Spring, Hibernate & JPA: Calling persist on entitymanager does not seem to commit to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374886/spring-hibernate-jpa-calling-persist-on-entitymanager-does-not-seem-to-commi?rq=1)

These suggest that you should try adding `em.flush()` after the `em.persist(chain)`, and altering the `@transactional` annotations

You should also check that you have enabled transactional annotations through a line such as :

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

in your .xml configuration

Comment: The thing is that there is no Exception, code is executed, but there is no record put on database.

Comment: Hmm, definitely try em.flush() then.

Comment: when i add `flush()` i got `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress` should i post full trace?

Comment: Well, that is a clearer error: have you tried annotating the method with @transactional?

Comment: my class have `@transactional` annotation however i did as you adviced and exception remains.

Comment: Have you enabled transactions annotations in your configuration file? ie have you added a line like: <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

Comment: i have `<tx:annotation-driven />` adding `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>` result in nothing.

Comment: i just saw that i get `AbstractSaveEventListener - delaying identity-insert due to no transaction in progress`

Comment: Why has this answer been accepted? It doesn't sound like it solved your problem. I'm having the same problem, transaction is there but EntityManager does not know about it. If I manually call em.joinTransaction() then it works, but why would I have to do that?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(entity);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

PS: You should set a generation method for your ID as well.

Comment: `Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead`

Comment: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction()

Comment: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Answer (score 1):

Can you post what exception are you getting? I will assume that your error is that your persistence.xml you don't specified your "Chain" Object.

You can specify using this tag

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

Or just

```
 <class>your.package.Chain</class>
```

Put this above *provider* tag.

Also, never set a number for a column tagged as @Id

When you use method save() with a Id column with setted value, hibernate
will try to **UPDATE** NOT INSERT your data.

Do this:
Create getEntityManager Method

```
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}
```

Then

```
@Transactional
public void saveChain(Chain chain) {

    chain.setDate(new Date());
    getEntityManager().persist(chain);
}
```

Comment: Still no exception and no record in database

Comment: OMG, i spent some hours with this problem =P  .. In my case I'm using Camel, Spring and Hibernate + JPA..  I forgot a little detail.  

Was missing the **@Transactional** annotation in  My **@Service** method.

Thanks for **the hint about flush**.  I've just put the flush and the  long awaited exception appears in the log.

nice link about possible causes :
http://www.scarba05.co.uk/blog/2010/02/hibernate-jpa-is-swallowing-my-data-no-save-no-error/

Comment: thanks you have saved my time. It was due to em.flush().

Answer (score 0):

Adding these to your `web.xml` may solve this problem:

```
<!-- Open Entity Manager in View filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

solved my problem using

```
org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager
```

hope this work!

Answer (score 0):

Use @EnableTransactionManagement in AppConfig Configuration file header

Answer (score 0):

You can open the new Transaction and then commit your records.

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "NameOfPersistenceUnit")
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

void someMethod(AccountCommodity accountCommodity){
     EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
     entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
     entityManager.persist(accountCommodity);
     entityManager.flush();
     entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
     entityManager.close();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to close EntityManager after creating it via EntityManagerFactory

Answer (score -1):

You will need to assign id generation strategy as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="Chain")
public class Chain implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
@Column(name = "date")
  private Date date;
@Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
//setters and getters
}
```

and in save method

```
  public int saveChain(Chain chain) {
        chain.setDate(new Date());
      //chain.setId((long)44);  remove this line
        Boolean a;
        em.persist(chain);

        return 222;
    }
```

if you assign Id, then hibernate/jpa will try to update record, which is not available, instead of inserting new record and I think will not throw exception.

Comment: try to manually flush with `em.flush()`, how transaction is configured?

Comment: u mean spring configuration? 
    `<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean> `

Comment: I just saw that i get `AbstractSaveEventListener - delaying identity-insert due to no transaction in progress`

Comment: you should apply `@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` over method `saveChain` to make sure transaction is not read only. by default with just `@Transactional` its readonly.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix the same problem by adding the Entity to **persistence.xml**:

```
<persistence-unit name="OwnerPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.test.domain.local.Entity</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes />
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```